# How to check GoogleSignIn return the picture that the user has uploaded and not default image set by Google

Tags: android, ios, google-api, google-play, google-signin

When I call https://oauth2.googleapis.com I can retrieve the picture of the user OR the default dummy picture that google assign to the user like the one below :

[image]

How to know if the API returns me the default dummy picture assigned by google or if it's return me the picture uploaded by the user?